# Serial communication problem NodeMCU

Tags: serial, programming, nodemcu, python

this is my first post here. Before I ask you my problem, I'm sorry if I'm wrong to write but my English is bad.

So, my problem is this: I'm developing a "client-server" system with serial communication between my computer and the NodeMCU. The PC will send a message (an integer) to the Node which makes certain things based on the number. At the end of the work the Node will send an ACK to the server (an integer).
I programmed the NodeMCU using the Arduino tool and in the first preliminary tests everything worked: the Node received and answered correctly. Then I wrote a script in Python to automate the thing and that's where the problems start. Communication takes place correctly but the messages that the Node sends to the PC are dirty. At the beginning of the buffer there are some illegible bits while at the end of the buffer there is the correct message. I did the same test with the Arduino Uno and this works perfectly.

Can you give me a reason for this problem and in case a solution? 
Thanks in advance!

---

NodeMCU:

```
void setup( )
    {
        Serial.begin( 9600 );
        while ( !Serial );
    }

void loop( )
    {
        if( Serial )
            {
                Serial.write( (int)12 );
            }
    }
```

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial

port = '/dev/cu.wchusbserial1420'

ard = serial.Serial(port,9600,timeout=5)

x = ard.read(1)
x = int( x )

print x
```

---

(I am attaching some screenshots)

[image]

[image]

Comment: post your code as text, not pictures.

Comment: Try `ard.flushInput()` instead of `ard.flush()`

Comment: what about a number >255? hows that work?

Comment: Opening the serial port might cause a reset of the NodeMCU through the DTR/RTS pins. You might want to wait a second after opening, then read and flush all the input on the COM port and then start reading.

Comment: Use `x = ord(x)` instead of `x = int( x )`. `ord()` converts character to it's DEC value. 'int() ` converts only number characters to number.

Comment: try `Serial.println(String(x));` to format it for consumption by your python parser. It has more overhead than raw multi-byte binary values, but will work on any int.